# Personalize button-toggle-group (Material 2)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I have this button group toggle with Material 2 (Angular 5)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label>Days of Week</label>
    <mat-button-toggle-group multiple formControlName="days_service" #group="matButtonToggleGroup" >
        <mat-button-toggle [value]="days.value" *ngFor='let days of days_service'>
            {{ days.alias }}
        </mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

This is my button group

[image]

But, I'd like to change it to that

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that the styling of the mat-button-toggle should center the text by default. Are the css properties from material applied to the elements in your template?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solve this problem override the custom directives

```
mat-button-toggle {
    border: 1px solid #f28628;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right:3px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    font-family: 'Nunito Semibold', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-style: bold;
}

.mat-button-toggle-disabled {
    border: 1px solid #c5c0c7;
    background-color: #e1dde5;
}

div.center-text {
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
```

Comment: What is `center-text` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use below `CSS` code:

```
.mat-button-toggle-checked {
   border: 1px solid #c5c0c7;
   background-color: #e1dde5; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code example that uses appearance="legacy"

HTML

```
<div class="custom-mat-div" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <mat-button-toggle-group appearance="legacy">
    <mat-button-toggle disableRipple="true" checked="true" value="animals">Animals
    </mat-button-toggle>
    <mat-button-toggle disableRipple="true" value="humans">Humans
    </mat-button-toggle>
  </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

CSS

```
:host ::ng-deep .custom-mat-div {
    .mat-button-toggle-group {
        box-shadow: none !important;
        .mat-button-toggle-checked .mat-button-toggle-button {
            background: #db4444 !important;
        }
    }
    mat-button-toggle {
        box-shadow   : 0px 0.5px 2px #8c69b540;
        border       : 1px solid #0000001a;
        border-radius: 17px !important;
        @include margin-right(10px);
        mat-button-toggle-checked {
            color: #fff !important;
            background-color: #db4444 !important;
        }
        button {
            white-space   : nowrap;
            display       : flex;
            align-items   : center;
            letter-spacing: 0px;
            font-size     : 14px;
            height        : 33px;
            padding         : 5px 16px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffffff 0%, #eaeef4 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
            box-shadow      : 0px 0.5px 2px #8c69b540;
            border-radius   : 17px;
            &.active,
            &:hover {
                background-color: #db4444;
            }
        }
    }
    .mat-button-toggle-label-content{
        padding: 0px;
    }
    .mat-button-toggle-group .mat-button-toggle-button {
        background: none !important;
    }
}
```